# Can I use GoogleApiClient to connect to my own GAE Endpoints API?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-app-engine

Can I use GoogleApiClient to connect to my own GAE Endpoints API?
Perhaps by adding some kind of special scope?

I know it's probably impossible (after all, my own API isn't Google's) but I'd love to leverage the G+ log in functionality!

Thanks and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand the question yet.  Your endpoints library can see if a user is logged in by looking at the User parameter.  The example near the [end of Lesson 2](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud859/l-1215898636/m-1452208622) of [Udacity's course](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud859) integrates with G+ log-in.

Comment: There's a Python example of using the Python version of the API client to call a custom app via Endpoints in my I/O 2013 talk: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/333307296  The general answer is yes, you can build your app's API with Endpoints, then call it with the Google API client.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Are you aware of a java example? dyoo, i'll take a look at the link you posted as well.

Comment: Dan, I speed-listened to your presentation, it's cool but I'm not sure if it's answering my question. To be specific, I meant if I can use something like this but for my own Endpoints API.
 <code>       final GoogleApiClient.Builder b = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(manager.activity())
                .setAccountName(userAccountName)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(apiConnectionHandler)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(apiConnectionHandler)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE);</code>

Comment: [continued] instead of using the GoogleAccountCredential directly. (just the way I don't need to use GoogleAccountCredential to say log into G+ and GDrive). Thanks.

Comment: Dyoo, thanks a lot but the presentation you supplied stops at the part I care about -- how you would do the client side.  It only has details on the backend setup, which I already understand and have done. Thx